# Prompt for User Input From Within a Subshell

Tags: node.js, task

I am using [task](https://github.com/go-task/task) to run various build steps in parallel. It is like 1000% faster then doing it all synchronously. However, it seems that `task` uses all these different subshells. I want to be able to prompt the user for their input using a node program. However, when node logs and attempts to prompt from `task` its restamped with `task`s logger and I cannot get the fancy node prompt to show up.

I was wondering what the best way of solving this would be. Ideally, I could use a one-liner that attaches whatever code `task` runs to the main terminal Window so that the node script can do its thing. However, if that's not possible I'm open to other ideas. I was thinking of creating a bash alias for `task` that is the front end and then I could post the messages I want logged while node is listening to the socket that task posts onto. I just want to make sure there is no easy way of handling this before I create a custom solution.

Thanks.